# link inside an animated div issue

Tags: css, html, animation

For some reason, I can not click on links that are in animated divs. They are some clouds that move arround.

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="clouds">
    <div class="cloud1"><a href="/pages/porfolio.html"><img src="../images/cloud_portfolio.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="cloud2"><img src="../images/clouds_customer.png"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  width: 1100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index:1;
}
#clouds {
  top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: move 40s infinite linear;  
  -moz-animation: move 40s infinite linear;  
  -ms-animation: move 40s infinite linear;
  z-index: 2;

}
#clouds a{
  cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Comment: could you include the actual animation code ass well perhaps? having difficulty reproducing the problem without the actual move: http://jsfiddle.net/3McEZ/

Comment: Thanks. I updated! On jsfiddle it works. Then it is a problem with some other element that is blocking the links, no?

Comment: (don't see the animation code anywhere, still a bit curious after the effect) Yep, probably some other element on top of it. Try the 3d view in the recent firefox, the only thing it is actually usefull for... Or just right click on the link in chrome and choose 'inspect element' and see wich element actually gets inspected. That will be the guilty one...

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, I had some things to do. http://jsfiddle.net/3McEZ/3/ Yes, it was a div to big that was over the animation. Now it is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: you could style that link instead of putting it in a div

Comment: @Claudiu If you solved this problem answer to the question with a solution for the people who may see this in the future and mark it as solved please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never worked with CSS-animation but isn't it possible that you move the images under another element thus making the links unclickable? Are you seeing this in every browser and does removing the animation really make a difference?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This actually prooved to be what was wrong in the comments of the question.